# Is the path selected by the NSOpenPanel permanent valid

Tags: swift, macos, nsopenpanel

I don't quite understand how to describe the problem.

In the introduction of `NSOpenPanel`, there is such a sentence, "When the user chooses a file to open, macOS adds that file to the app’s sandbox" 
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel)

When I use `NSOpenPanel` to open a folder, I can get the path of this folder, and my application can operate on the file of this folder, for example, I can choose to copy files to this folder.

What I want to know is if my program runs in the sandbox, the permissions of the folder that `NSOpenPanel` uses to get the application is permanent or temporary. That is, under what conditions my application will lose control of this folder.

Comment: Per [App Sandbox in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW4): "By default, files opened or saved by the user remain within your sandbox until your app terminates, except for files that were open at the time that your app terminates. Such files reopen automatically by way of the macOS Resume feature the next time your app launches, and are automatically added back to your app’s sandbox."

Comment: It continues: "To provide persistent access to resources located outside of your container, in a way that doesn’t depend on Resume, use security-scoped bookmarks as explained in [Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16)."

Comment: If you search for [security scoped bookmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+security+scoped+bookmarks), you'll find tons of discussions on this topic.